# Node.js, Sails.js servers time out

Tags: node.js, timeout, sails.js, ttl

**Environment**: Windows Server 2008

I have a Node.js and a Sails.js apps. For example, my Node.js app does something like this:

```
http.createServer(function(req,res){...}).listen(8000);
```

Both are really simple apps, but I need them available at all times. I had problems creating a Windows Service, so i created a task for each app in the Task Scheduler.

They seem to be working fine except for when the apps haven't been used for over an hour or so (not sure on the exact timing). After some time when I go to localhost:8000, my Node.js app (same with my Sails.js app) responds only after about 10-20 seconds, and in less than a second in the following requests.

I am thinking about writing another task :) - a warm-up script that will send periodic requests to keep the apps running. But there's gotta be a better way! Is there a server timeout setting in Node.js/Sails.js that can be disabled/modified?

Comment: You get any info in terminal for node application when it takes so long?

Comment: Since it's running as a task - I don't get to see the console. But it's a good idea, I'm gonna try running it from the command line instead of a task, and see what happens.

Comment: You can also log output to a file. ; )